# could someone help me figure out why this doesn't work?

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements

```
i=0

if [$i -eq 0]
then 
   echo "i is equal to 0"
else 
   echo "NOT EQUAL <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>"
fi
```

it is part of a bash script and it always takes the else branch. I'm completely new to bash so its probably something silly

Comment: An alternative to `[ $i -eq 0 ]` might be `((i==0))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need `[ $i` instead of `[$i`.

This is because the `[` is a builtin command and `$i` should be it's first parameter. If you miss the space between command and parameter, then the shell will look for `[$i` command and after evaluation will tell you that there is no `[0` command to be executed.

Comment: yep. i tend to write it this way "if [ $x comp $y ]; then" because I like my if and then on the same line.

Comment: Hmmno, `[` is not a builtin command: it is a (sym)link to the `test` command. In fact, the only difference between `test` and `[` is that the `[` form requires a `]` as the last argument ;) Try `which [` in your shell.

Comment: @fge: it depends on shell implementation. On older OSes it used to be a symlink. All modern shells has such builtin. Run `type [` to see.

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces after '[' and before ']'. '[' is a command.